# Search for <> in a sumif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This sounds like such a basic question but i'm struggling to find a solution.

I have a sumif and want the criteria to be <>. I don't want to use <> as it normally is used, but want to actually search for those characters in the range.

I've tried 2 sets of quotation marks but have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.

Use "=<>"